# Kubernetes deployment configuration yaml - Escaping Special Characters

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I would like to set the Keycloak Admin Password in my Kubernetes deployment.yaml. To do so I have added this to my environment variables:

```
- name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD
  value: 'ExamplePassword123£'
```

By adding the `£` character I can no longer log into Keycloak with the password. I've tried:

```
£
\£
\u00a3
Removing the quotes
```

`ExamplePassword123` is fine so it definitely is the addition of this character.

How can I correctly escape the `£` character?

Comment: have you tried `\u00a3` with double quotes instead of single quotes ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try base64-encoding it into a secret and then refer to it using something like:

```
- name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: name-of-secret
      key: password
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Kustomize to generate your secrets. When you develop `kustomize generator`, you don't need to base64 encode the values. Follow this [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configmap-secret/managing-secret-using-kustomize/#create-the-secret) for more information